# How are chiral bosons defined?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, field-theory, fermions, bosons, chirality

What is the definition of chiral bosons? Until now I only knew the derivation of the chiral fermions (used in the Dirac field equation).

Comment: They are solutions to the Klein Gordon equation with zero mass

Comment: [Floreanini & Jackiw 1987](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.59.1873).

Comment: Clear! Thanks a lot